# Stripe: How do I add and store additional form elements with javascript?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, stripe-payments

I am trying store data from additional inputs in the form, not just the credit card information.

Here is what the form looks like: 
[form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XlyH.png)

The payment works and the booking gets stored in the database. I am struggling to figure out how to also get the additional form inputs "a link to your project" and "additional info" stored in the DB as well.

Here is what the code likes on the server:

```
router.route('/pay')
 .post(async (req, res, next) => {
   let artist = req.session.artist;
   let price = req.session.price;
   let user = req.session.user;
   let email = req.session.userEmail;

   price *= 100;

   const {
     paymentMethodId,
     paymentIntentId,
     currency,
     useStripeSdk
   } = req.body;

   try {
     let intent;
     if (paymentMethodId) {
       // Create new PaymentIntent with a PaymentMethod ID from the client.
       intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
         amount: price,
         currency: currency,
         receipt_email: email,
         payment_method: paymentMethodId,
         confirmation_method: 'manual',
         confirm: true,
         // If a mobile client passes `useStripeSdk`, set `use_stripe_sdk=true`
         // to take advantage of new authentication features in mobile SDKs
         use_stripe_sdk: useStripeSdk
       });
       // After create, if the PaymentIntent's status is succeeded, fulfill the order.
     } else if (paymentIntentId) {
       // Confirm the PaymentIntent to finalize payment after handling a required action
       // on the client.
       intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(paymentIntentId);
       // After confirm, if the PaymentIntent's status is succeeded, fulfill the order.
     }

     let newBooking = await Booking.create({
       artist,
       user,
       price,
       projectLink: req.body.projectLink,
       additionalInfo: req.body.additionalInfo
     });
     console.log(newBooking)

     let data = {
       intent: generateResponse(intent)
     };

     res.send(data);
   } catch (e) {
     // Handle "hard declines" e.g. insufficient funds, expired card, etc
     // See https://stripe.com/docs/declines/codes for more
     res.send({
       error: e.message
     });
   }
 });
```

And here is what it looks like on the client:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_ycz...');
// A reference to Stripe.js
var stripe;

var orderData = {
  items: [{
    id: "photo-subscription"
  }],
  currency: "usd"
};

// Disable the button until we have Stripe set up on the page
document.querySelector(".disable").disabled = true;

fetch("/stripe-key")
  .then(function (result) {
    return result.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    return setupElements(data);

  })
  .then(function ({
    stripe,
    card,
    clientSecret
  }) {
    document.querySelector(".disable").disabled = false;
    var form = document.getElementById("payment-form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const projectLink = document.getElementById('projectLink').value;
      const additionalInfo = document.getElementById('additionalInfo').value;

      pay(stripe, card, clientSecret, projectLink, additionalInfo);
      console.log(projectLink, additionalInfo)


    });
  });

var setupElements = function (data) {
  stripe = Stripe(data.publishableKey);
  /* ------- Set up Stripe Elements to use in checkout form ------- */
  var elements = stripe.elements();
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: "#32325d",
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
      fontSize: "16px",
      "::placeholder": {
        color: "#aab7c4"
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: "#fa755a",
      iconColor: "#fa755a"
    }
  };

  var card = elements.create("card", {
    style: style
  });
  card.mount("#card-element");

  return {
    stripe: stripe,
    card: card,
    clientSecret: data.clientSecret
  };
};

var handleAction = function (clientSecret, projectLink, additionalInfo) {
  stripe.handleCardAction(clientSecret).then(function (data) {
    if (data.error) {
      showError("Your card was not authenticated, please try again");
    } else if (data.paymentIntent.status === "requires_confirmation") {
      fetch("/pay", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            paymentIntentId: data.paymentIntent.id
          })

        })
        .then(function (result) {
          return result.json();
        })
        .then(function (json) {
          if (json.error) {
            showError(json.error);
          } else {
            orderComplete(clientSecret);
          }
        });
    }

  });
};

/*
 * Collect card details and pay for the order
 */
var pay = function (stripe, card) {
  changeLoadingState(true);

  // Collects card details and creates a PaymentMethod
  stripe
    .createPaymentMethod("card", card)
    .then(function (result) {
      if (result.error) {
        showError(result.error.message);
      } else {
        orderData.paymentMethodId = result.paymentMethod.id;


        return fetch("/pay", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(orderData)
        });
      }
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      return result.json();

    })
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.intent.error) {
        showError(response.intent.error);
      } else if (response.intent.requiresAction) {
        // Request authentication
        handleAction(response.intent.clientSecret);
      } else {
        orderComplete(response.intent.clientSecret);
      }
    });
};
```

On the server side, I have used req.body for both inputs on Booking.create(...) but I'm not sure how to get that from the client using Stripe's code. On the client side, I tried adding the form data to the fetch API call on /pay but couldn't figure out how to get it to work. If anyone has any ideas, that would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the additional info you want as part of the `body` of `fetch("/pay")`, which is how it would get to the server side.  You should add them as arguments to your client side `pay()` function, and then pass them in the body of that `fetch` request.